# Process thread to start address and symbol name mapping

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I can enumerate through all modules and threads with their start address of a process with a [Toolhelp32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686837(v=vs.85).aspx) functions. What is the method used to get the  **module name** that the thread is running preferably with function name? Example of this information is the Process Explorer's Threads view:

[image: Process explorer Threads list]

Comment: You have two separate questions here: (1) How do I get the start address of a thread in a (different?) process? (2) Given an address, how do I get the module name (and function, and offset)?

Comment: Clarified the question that I am looking specifically for the module name and preferably the function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enumerate the modules in the process. You say you can already do that.
2. Call `GetModuleInformation` for each module to find its base address (well, you already know that) and the size of the module image.
3. That information gives you the start and end of the module. Then you just need to find which module has a start and end address in which the thread start address is contained.